# RDBMS table extracts Hadoop or spark.?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

Can someone give me some tips on how to extract the data from the RDBMS( Teradata,oracle, db2 etc ) table s onto to Hadoop HDFS or spark.

Comment: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using SQOOP... Latest version of the SQOOP documentation can be found in the below link,

http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html